# EF Competing SaveChanges() Calls

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, transactions, sqlbulkcopy

I am building a batch processing system.  Batches of `Units` come in quantities from 20-1000.  Each `Unit` is essentially a hierarchy of models (one main model and many child models).  My task involves saving each model hierarchy to a database as a single transaction (either each hierarchy commits or it rolls back).  Unfortunately `EF` was unable to handle two portions of the model hierarchy due to their potential to contain thousands of records.

What I've done to resolve this is set up `SqlBulkCopy` to handle these two potentially high count models and let `EF` handle the rest of the inserts (and referential integrity).

**Batch Loop:**

```
foreach (var unitDetails in BatchUnits)
{
  var unitOfWork = new Unit(unitDetails);
  Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
      unitOfWork.ProcessX(); // data preparation
      unitOfWork.ProcessY(); // data preparation
      unitOfWork.PersistCase();
    });
}
```

**Unit:**

```
class Unit
{
  public PersistCase()
  {
    using (var dbContext = new CustomDbContext())
    {
      // Need an explicit transaction so that 
      // EF + SqlBulkCopy act as a single block
      using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required,
        new TransactionOptions() {
          IsolationLevel = System.Transaction.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted
        }))
      {
        // Let EF Insert most of the records
        // Note Insert is all it is doing, no update or delete
        dbContext.Units.Add(thisUnit);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();  // deadlocks, DbConcurrencyExceptions here

        // Copy Auto Inc Generated Id (set by EF) to DataTables
        // for referential integrity of SqlBulkCopy inserts
        CopyGeneratedId(thisUnit.AutoIncrementedId, dataTables);

        // Execute SqlBulkCopy for potentially numerous model #1
        SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy1 = new SqlBulkCopy(...);
        ...
        bulkCopy1.WriteToServer(dataTables["#1"]);

        // Execute SqlBulkCopy for potentially number model #2
        SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy2 = new SqlBulkCopy(...);
        ...
        bulkCopy2.WriteToServer(dataTables["#2"]);

        // Commit transaction
        scope.Complete();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Right now I'm essentially stuck between a rock and a hard place.  If I leave the `IsolationLevel` set to `ReadCommitted`, I get deadlocks between `EF` `INSERT` statements in different `Tasks`.

If I set the `IsolationLevel` to `ReadUncommitted` (which I thought would be fine since I'm not doing any `SELECTs`) I get `DbConcurrencyExceptions`.

I've been unable to find any good information about `DbConcurrencyExceptions` and `Entity Framework` but I'm guessing that `ReadUncommitted` is essentially causing `EF` to receive invalid "rows inserted" information.

**UPDATE**

Here is some background information on what is actually causing my deadlocking issues while doing INSERTS:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/562148/how-to-avoid-using-scope-identity-based-insert-commands-on-sql-server-2005

Apparently this same issue was present a few years ago when Linq To SQL came out and Microsoft fixed it by changing how scope_identity() gets selected.  Not sure why their position has changed to this being a SQL Server problem when the same issue came up with Entity Framework.

Comment: _competing_ or _completing_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is explained fairly well here:  http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/562148/how-to-avoid-using-scope-identity-based-insert-commands-on-sql-server-2005

Essentially its an internal EF issue.  I migrated my code to use Linq To SQL and it now works fine (no longer does the unnecessary `SELECT` for the identity value).

Relevant quote from the exact same issue in Linq To Sql which was fixed:

> When a table has an identity column, Linq to SQL generates extremely
>   inefficient SQL for insertion into such a table. Assume the table is
>   Order and the identiy column is Id. The SQL generated is:
>
> exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO [dbo].[Order]([Colum1], [Column2])
>   VALUES (@p0, @p1)
>
> SELECT [t0].[Id] FROM [dbo].[Order] AS [t0] WHERE [t0].[Id] =
>   (SCOPE_IDENTITY()) ',N'@p0 int,@p1 int,@p0=124,@p1=432
>
> As one can see instead of returning SCOPE_IDENTITY() directly by using
>   'SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()', the generated SQL performs a SELECT on the
>   Id column using the value returned by SCOPE_IDENTITY(). When the
>   number of the records in the table is large, this significantly slows
>   down the insertion. When the table is partitioned, the problem gets
>   even worse.